# Perform an operation to a variable. Subtracting 1

Tags: bash, variables, operation

I have a question. I have a bash script that works fine.

```
    while read val1 val2 val3
    do
    echo "ncap2 -Oh -s'TOPOBATHY(($val1,$val2))=$val3.'"
    done < $tmpdir/tmp1 > $tmpdir/tmp2
```

I would like just to perform one operation to val1 and val2, subtracting 1. I tried to subtract directly but it does not work. Is there a way to do that. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
    while read val1 val2 val3
    do
    echo "ncap2 -Oh -s'TOPOBATHY(($val1-1),($val2-1))=$val3.'"
    done < $tmpdir/tmp1 > $tmpdir/tmp2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform (integer) arithmetic on variables within Bash with [this syntax](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression)

For your specific case, you can either set the new values of the variables before calling them in `echo`:

```
val1=$((val1 - 1))
```

or you can put it in-line:

```
echo "ncap2 -Oh -s'TOPOBATHY($((val1 - 1)),$((val2 - 1 )))=$val3.'"
```

Of course, you are presently relying on the user to input suitable values, as there's no error-checking/input sanitisation in the example you provide.